# Azure Mobile Server Script - Get column value from another table

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-mobile-services

I'm working with Azure Mobile Services. I've got two tables and what I'm trying to do is to grab a column value from TableA, by checking where it matches with a column value from TableB when I run an insert on TableB.

My insert server script is as follows:

```
function insert(item, user, request) {

    var TableA_Table = tables.getTable('TableA');

    tableA_Table
        .where({ columnValue: item.columnValue })
        .read ({ success: setItemColumnValue });

    request.execute();

    function setItemColumnValue(result)
    {
        item.tableA_id = result.id;
    }
}
```

I've confirmed that my tableA_Table.where command is pulling the correct row from TableA, but when I enter a console.log(result) within the setItemColumnValue function, it prints undefined.

All the documentation I've found shows code similar to mine but I just can't figure out where I'm going wrong.
Any help appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems in your script. First, you have to remember is that the table access code is asynchronous. What is happening is that the function is the callback function 'setItemColumnValue' is only being called after `request.execute();`, which means that the item would be inserted without the `tableA_id` member set. The other issue is that the `read` success callback returns *an array of results*, not a single result (just like a SQL `SELECT FROM` statement), so that array doesn't have the `id` field - its members have it. Try rewriting the code somehow like the code below and this should work.

```
function insert(item, user, request) {

    var TableA_Table = tables.getTable('TableA');

    tableA_Table
        .where({ columnValue: item.columnValue })
        .read ({ success: setItemColumnValue });

    function setItemColumnValue(results)
    {
        if (results.length === 0) {
            // what should it do if there is no matching on table A?
            // Assuming here that this is an error.
            request.respond(statusCodes.BAD_REQUEST, { error: 'No matching item in table A' });
        } else if (results.length === 1) {
            item.tableA_id = results[0].id;
            request.execute();
        } else {
            // what should it do if there are multiple matches on table A?
            // Assuming here that this is an error.
            request.respond(statusCodes.BAD_REQUEST, { error: 'Multiple matches in table A' });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Carlos! I have updated my code as you mentioned, I am now directly accessing the id values of the members of the array and I now understand the asynchronous nature of the callback functions. The only remaining issue I have is that Azure is throwing 'Error: Execute cannot be called more than once' even though my second request.execute is within my setItemColumnValue function as you've laid out. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to remove the call to `request.execute()` following the `read` call. Since on the read callback all code paths will respond to the request (either by calling `request.respond` or `request.execute`), the original one isn't required anymore. I updated the code in the answer.

Comment: In your answer you have `item.TableA_id = result.id` but since results is an array shouldn't it be `results[0].id`?

Comment: @winnicki you're correct, I just edited the post with that update. Thanks for catching that.